# Is it possible to contribute to academic research after retirement from the industry?

Tags: research-process, independent-researcher, retirement

Currently, I have a master’s of science in mathematics and a potential plan to couple my qualifications with a masters of science in analytics. I am actually nowhere close to being retired in the industry. But thinking way beyond the scope of the near future, I am curious if there is any possibility for someone who officially is retired from the industry to contribute to academic research? If so, how should a recent graduate prepare himself to make this a possibility.

Ideally, I would like to contribute to research in machine learning after completing a rewarding career as a data scientist. I have been continually expanding my knowledge by reading mathematical references on the train ride to work each day.

Comment: The only problem you might face is that some journals won't consider submissions if you don't have an official academic affiliation (including a valid academic email address). That said, nothing prevents you from publishing online in any venue that does not screen submissions on academic affiliation: if your work is good and a relevant contribution to a field, it will be recognized as such and cited, no matter where it is published (as long as it is in a somewhat known journal or pre-print repository).

Comment: I've seen a full-blown academic paper with a prison as author's address. It was an infamous convict in campus shooting, who was however capable of doing research even after being convicted. Now, it __that__ works out...

Comment: @OlegLobachev DOI, or it didn't happen. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

A non-negligible amount of people start a PhD after retirement from industry. Depending on where you are in the world, if there are coursework requirements, having a master's may exempt you, so this can give you a fairly unrestrictive but very beneficial environment to do research in. If furthermore you have a comfortable retirement package and don't need funding you will be a very attractive candidate.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a number of professors contribute to their field after getting the title "professor emeritus".

One example would be with  [Terrence C. Mills](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Terence_Mills/info) who is still producing material on applied time series analysis dispite of being a retired professor.

Based on this it seems that academics can still make contributions to their field regardless of the fact that they are retired.

Comment: Would it matter if you have a Ph.D. or not? I know that there are some publications that don't have an education requirement, but am I severely limited in this respect due to the lack of Ph.D.?